# Event that is fired when scrolling STOPS - flex

Tags: apache-flex, scroll

Is there a way to start an event when the verticalscrollbar in mx textarea stops being scrolled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution :

```
        private function init():void{
            area.addEventListener(ScrollEvent.SCROLL,onScroll)
            timer = new Timer(1000);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, startFun);
            timer.start();  
        }

        private function onScroll(e:Event):void{
            timer.stop()    
            colored=false
            timer.start()   
        }


        private function startFun(e:Event):void{


            while(!colored){

                    area.text="Bye Bye cruel world !"
                    colored=true;
            }
        }
```